# value is only present inside a function how to access it outside

Tags: javascript, sqlite, graphql

I have a function like this the value of the row is only accessible insde that {(  )} outside it shows undefined how can i access the value of row outside the function.

```
feed: () => {
      var link;
      db.all("SELECT * from Link", (error, rows) => {
        link = rows;
      //  console.log(link);/// it will print the value here
      });

      console.log(link);// it shows undefined

      return link;
    }
```

Comment: `db.all()`is an asynchronous function, so you have to wait for it to be finished to be able to access the value outside of it. Do you know about synchronous/asynchronous behavior?